# Retrieving a Dynamically Generated TextBox Content in a GridView in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

I have the following RowDataBound method for GridView2

```
protected void GridView2_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                List<TextBox> list = new List<TextBox>(); 
                if (ViewState["Table"] != null)
                    Assessments = (DataTable)ViewState["Table"]; 
                int count = 1;
                foreach (DataRow row in Assessments.Rows)
                {
                    TextBox txt = new TextBox();
                    txt.ID = "AsTxt"; 
                    txt.Text = string.Empty;
                    txt.TextChanged += OnTextChanged; 
                    e.Row.Cells[count].Controls.Add(txt);
                    count += 2;
                    listd.Add((e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView).Row[0].ToString() + "Txt");
                }
            }
        }
```

And the following event (Button Click) to retrieve whatever written in the text box in the GridView

```
protected void CalculateBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GridViewRow rr = GridView2.Rows[0];
            TextBox rrrr = (rr.FindControl("AsTxt") as TextBox); 
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('" + rrrr.Text + "')", true);
        }
```

I always get NullReferenceException. That mean the TextBox object (rrrr) is null always. I am sure that the text object sits in GridView2.Rows[0].

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is known issue with the `Dynamical` created controls in asp. So if you want to use the created control on your `postback` then I suggest that you declare your controls outside the page_int and do your initialization in the init then use them with their name instead of find control.

Look at this blog this might help you

http://techbrij.com/retrieve-value-of-dynamic-controls-in-asp-net

Comment: can u clarify a bit? Example whats the page_init?

Comment: [Here is more info on the page lifecycle ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28v=vs.85%29.aspx )

Comment: @codeofcode i still dont know how many controls i need so how can i declare them outside the page_int?

Comment: Then you can use session or something which will give save all required info about your controls and then by checking that value in `InIt` you can recreate them.

Comment: Updated the answer with the blog link check out .

Comment: how can I make the number of rows dynamic as well. It seems in the link is constant. Let say I wanna get the number of rows from an input TextBox.

Comment: What do you mean by the dynamic rows ? Its not clear what you need, If its completely different question then ask a new question with details. And if this answer helped you then accept it as answer so question can be closed .

Comment: if you examine the code in the link you'll see that the number of rows is set to 5 in CreateDynamicTable() function. In my code I need to make this variable for example the user can enter it using input textbox for example. I tried to do it but it gives me error.

Comment: Don't take me wrong, but it is not good to discuss new question in comments. You can post new question with the your new code and new exception with details as there are more good people than me who can also give there insight.Also if you explain it better then only I will able to give you the solution. So need more details like what is the exception and all